# Avoid duplication in nginx redirects config?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, https, redirect, http2

Setting up redirects *www* → *non-www* and *HTTP* → *HTTPS* at the same time, I ran into duplication issue that I fail to overcome.

On my domain—let it be `example.com`—I have a website with primary name `another.example.com`. I want the requests to `example.com`, `www.example.com`, and `www.another.example.com` to be redirected to `another.example.com`, and all HTTP requests to be redirected to HTTPS at the same time; I also want to support HTTP/2 and IPv6.

I have no issue with getting this to work, but I fail to get rid of duplicating a substantial part of configuration file (namely HTTPS certificate settings). All attempts to reduce duplication cause one or more or all redirects to stop working (sometimes along with HTTP/2).

Please take a look at the config and suggest how to clean it up:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.another.example.com www.example.com another.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://another.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name www.another.example.com www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://another.example.com$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    server_name another.example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/another.example.com;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

Comment: See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www/43089681#43089681) on SO.

Comment: Alternatively, move common settings into a dedicated config and rely on `include`.

Comment: @RichardSmith after moving four duplicate strings to the outer block (and deletining them in both inner blocks), I get configuration errors: `nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.2" in /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:11
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.3" in /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:11
nginx: [emerg] "ssl_prefer_server_ciphers" directive is duplicate in /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:12
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: It looks like you have duplicate statements somewhere. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes, you’re right. But after I tracked down the duplication, another problem arose: there’re actually multiple top-level domains in my nginx config. If I move SSL configuration from a server block to the top level, then only one domain (e.g., `example.com`) will be working.

Comment: In which case your original setup is probably the best you can achieve. If you have a large number of duplicated statements you could place them into an included file.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    server_name another.example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/another.example.com;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.another.example.com www.example.com example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://another.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.another.example.com www.example.com another.example.com example.com;
    location / {
        if ($host !~* ^(www)) {
          rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://another.example.com/$1 permanent;
        }
    }
}
```